# Remove part of url in specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, joomla, url-rewriting

I am using a module for joomla called RokMiniEvents but there is a problem, once you use the navigation it adds a path to the events url: "/modules/mod_rokminievents3"..

Let's say the working url is this:

```
<a class="rme-title" href="/td/index.php/component/jevents/icalrepeat.detail/2014/07/22title=proto-seminario/0/-/-?rp_id=2&amp;Itemid=0">Event name</a>
```

But once you use the Navigation it becomes:

```
<a class="rme-title" href="/td/modules/mod_rokminievents3/index.php/component/jevents/icalrepeat.detail/2014/07/22title=/0/-/-?rp_id=2&amp;Itemid=0">Πρωτο Σεμιναριο</a>
```

I would like to use something like:
where **a** with **class="rme-title"** replace the **/mod_rokminievents3** with nothing..

Is that possible with javascript or any other language ? I've seen a lot of answers here but without the class selection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the elements and replace that part of the href with nothing using String.replace

```
$('a.rme-title').attr('href', function(_, href) {
    return href.replace('/mod_rokminievents3','');
});
```

Comment: I added it inside my index.php as `<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery('a.rme-title').attr('href', function(_, href) {
    return href.replace('/mod_rokminievents3','');
});
</script>`
But it's not working.
I replaced $ with jQuery because joomla uses it instead of $..

Comment: If you added that to the head, you'll need document.ready as well.

Comment: Okay I moved it over the </body> and it kinda works.. The problem is that the `mod_rokminievents3` doesn't exist unless you click the navigation. Here is the demo of the plugin [link](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla-extensions/rokminievents/) so you can see what kind of navigation I am talking about..In the demo they are using google calendar instead of Jevents so it works fine.

Comment: If the URL is somehow dynamically changed, you have to either alter the code that changes it, or run the above *after* the change has taken place. There is no magic solution.

Comment: I didn't manage to find the code that changes it, that why I wanted this alternative. Is it possible to run the above code once the user clicks or hovers on the link?

Comment: It probably is, but you really have to run it after the href has been changed, and that's probably more tricky than just adding an event handler ?

Comment: I guess it's complicated because I reported the bug 3 months ago to the company, and they didn't manage to fix it yet..

Comment: You're welcome! It probably is complicated, and would require changing the plugin, or at least knowing a lot more about how it works internally etc. so it's not something I can help you with here

Comment: Seeing you added this to your template index.php file, if you ever install an update for your template, it will override this changes. You should create a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the **rokminievents** extension.

Comment: no worries, the template is mine, thank you for the suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had same problem with this module, this is my solution:

In `modules/mod_rokminievents3/tmpl open default_item.php`

search the code:

```
<?php if (!$event->getLink()): ?>
    <span class="rme-title"><?php echo $event->getTitle(); ?></span>
<?php else: ?>
<?php
    $values   = $event->getLink();
    $internal = $values['internal'];
    $link     = $values['link'];
?>
    <a class="rme-title<?php echo $internal ? '' : ' rme-external-link'; ?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $event->getTitle(); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

finally get `$link` value and replace `"modules/mod_rokminievents3/"` by `""` here is the final code:

```
<?php if (!$event->getLink()): ?>
    <span class="rme-title"><?php echo $event->getTitle(); ?></span>
<?php else: ?>
<?php
    $values   = $event->getLink();
    $internal = $values['internal'];
    $link     = $values['link'];
    $link=str_replace ("modules/mod_rokminievents3/" ,"" , $link );
?>
    <a class="rme-title<?php echo $internal ? '' : ' rme-external-link'; ?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $event->getTitle(); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works for me.